# Ngx-formly check for focus in expressionProperties

Tags: html, angular, typescript, focus, ngx-formly

I am using ngx-formly `v: 5.5.10`. I try to check if field is focused in the expressionProperties.
This is necessary for changing the value based on focus.  Something like this:

```
expressionProperties: {
    'model.testField': (m) => {
        if (m.testField.value && testField.focus=true) {
            return x;
        } else {
            return y;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a formly built-in solution for checking focus in the expressionProperties?

 Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field instance is passed as a third argument of the expression callback:

```
expressionProperties: {
    'model.testField': (m, formState, field) => {
        if (m.testField.value && field.focus === true) {
            return x;
        } else {
            return y;
        }
    }
}
```